# Explode string to array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, input, field, explode

I have two input fields in PHP form. The fields need to be saved to array and the output should have word lenght of each words next to it in brackets. Also need to evaluate which input field 1 or 2 has longest word and how many words are in each fields. It shows error during execution. syntax error, unexpected end of file
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry8YA.png) [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYNoU.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html ">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title> Two Input field compare PHP </title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <?php

        echo "<br/>";

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $input1 = $_POST['input1'];
            $input2 = $_POST['input2'];
            //example $input1 = "Learning the PHP";
           //example $input2 = "Counting words and showing(7) like this word<< ";

            if (empty($input1)) {
                echo "You need to enter both fields !";
            }
            if (empty($input2)) {
                echo "You need to enter both fields !";
            }

              echo $input1;
              echo $input2;


            $inputarr1 = explode(" ", $input1);
            $inputarr2 = explode(" ", $input2);



            $longestlenghtarr1 = $longestlenghtarr2 = 0;

            $arraylength1 = sizeof($inputarr1);
            $arraylength2 = sizeof($inputarr2);



            $longest1 = $longest2 = 0;

            for ($x = 0; $x < arraylength1; $x++) {

            echo $inputarr1[$x] . " &lt; " . strlen($inputarr1[$x]) . " &gt; ";
                if (strlen($inputarr1[$x]) > $longest1) {
                    $longest1 = strlen($inputarr1[$x]);
                }
            }

            for ($y = 0; $y < arraylength2; $y++) {
                echo $inputarr2[$y] . " &lt; " . strlen($inputarr2[$y]) . " &gt; ";

                if (strlen($inputarr2[$y]) > $longest2) {
                    $longest2 = strlen($inputarr2[$y]);
                }
            }

                if ($longest1 > $longest2) {
                echo "<br/> The field 1 input has longest word of lenght " . $longest1." characters !";
                }

                if ($longest2 > $longest1) {
                        echo "<br/> The field 2 input has longest word of lenght " .$longest2." characters !";
                    }

                    if ($arraylength1 > $arraylength2) {
                    echo "<br/> The field 1 input has more words";}
                        if ($arraylength2 > $arraylength1) {
                            echo "<br/> The field 2 input has more words";
                        }

                        echo "<br/>";

              ?>

             <div>
                            <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

                Input Text 1 <br/>
                <input type="text" name="input1" /><br/>
                Input Text 2 <br/>
                <input type="text" name="input2" /><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>

        </div>

 </body></html>
```

Comment: Can you help further !

Comment: You really just need to debug it. Typically, when you encounter bugs the first thing you do is enable error reporting. But you've gone out of your way to disable it for some reason: `error_reporting(0);`. "It shows error during execution." What error? *You need to enter both fields !*?

Comment: I revised the code . Can you test again ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably wrong variable name - it should cause something like `Undefined index 'input1'` error.

Try replace `$POST_` with `$_POST` so you should have

```
$input1 = $_POST['input1']; 
$input2 = $_POST['input2'];
```

Comment: Still there is no output. Need to verify string explode and count

Comment: First of all as @HPierce sais try to replace `error_reporting(0);` with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` or just comment that line to see errors in your code. Your `explode` function first argument must be char (you have empty string) so put there a space between questionmarks. And than you have `$inputarr1 = explode...` but later you are iterating through `$inputarray1` (different array).